# Element prime order (EPO) group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

A  finite  group  $G$  is  called  EPO-group  if every  non-identity  element  of  $G$  has  prime  order.

For a given finite group $G$, let $\pi (G)$ denote the set of all prime divisors of $|G|$.

Does there exist  non-isomorphic EPO-groups $G_1$, $G_2$ of same order with $|\pi(G_i)|\geq 2$ , $i=1,2$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest examples are the groups denoted (147,4) and (147,5) in the SmallGroups library. They are both semidirect products $Z_7^2:Z_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, finite, non-isomorphic EPO-groups of the same order are possible. See DonAntonio's answer to a question in the recent thread

[When will two groups be isomorphic???](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099937/)

Comment: Thank you quasi for pointing out this post, but actually I want to know some thing more, which I have now explained in this edited post.